# Называние функции(метода), которая проверяет актуально ли значение

Tags: javascript, именование

Например, у меня есть переменные:

```js
const oldHash = /* some string */;
const newHash = /* some string */;
```

И я пишу функцию(метод), которая проверит их равенство, а суть проверки сказать, устарел `hash` или нет.

Пример:

```js
const what_is_the_name = () =>  oldHash === newHash
```

Или

```js
const what_is_the_name = () =>  oldHash !== newHash
```

Какое имя дать? Как принято такие функции(методы) называть?

Comment: Ну хоть одна светлая голова

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME хорошее предложение) Оформите в виде ответа. И наверное тут должно быть `const`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все стандартно, используя "говорящие" названия, глагол, и правила naming'a для bolean значений:

```
const checkIsNotExpired = (oldHash, newHash) => // ваша проверка
```

Разница с `isNotExpired` заключается в том что первая означает функцию, так как она начинается с глагола обозначающего ее действие, а вторая только то что она хранит (будет хранить) bolean значение.

[Лучшие Практики](https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices)

Comment: Второе, наверное, `checkIsExpired` должно быть?

Comment: Ну да всё верно и цитаты оттуда.

Comment: А я думаю она означает функцию потому что её можно вызвать.

Comment: Спасибо. Ставлю +1.

Answer (score 2):

Если их всех связывает `hash`, рука так и тянется сгруппировать всё в один объект)

```js
const hash = {
  old: "str",
  new: "str",
  
  isExpired: function() {
    // стрелочная не прокатит, у неё нет this.
    return this.old != this.new;
  }
};

console.log( hash.isExpired() );
```

Comment: Спасибо. +1. Но погляжу ещё...Может ещё варик предлжат)

Answer (score -1):

Другой вариант названия

```
const isExpired = () => oldHash !== newHash
const isNotExpired = () => oldHash === newHash
```

Добавлю немного слов [отсюда](https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices) чтоб было ясно.

> good variable and function names should be easy to understand and tell you what is going on — not more and not less.

Хорошее название переменной или же функции должно быть простым к пониманию и сообщить что происходит не больше и не меньше.

> A function called isLegalDrinkingAge() makes more sense than isOverEighteen() as the legal drinking age varies from country to country, and there are other things than drinking to consider that are limited by age.

Функция isLegalDrinkingAge() звучит более ясно нежели isOverEghteen() поскольку возраст распития алкоголя варьируется от страны к стране.

Comment: По best-practice, названия функций должны начинатся с глагола. То есть функцию лучше назвать `checkIsNotExpired`, а `isNotExpired` - отличный вариант для переменной, которая содержит результат проверки.

Comment: Без проблем все думаю const isExpired это что? toString к примеру

Comment: Это функция. Один из вариантов записи функций в js - через переменную. Но это функция)

Comment: Ну тогда is это не глагол вовсе?

Comment: Для ясности добавил не много слов

Comment: Ребята зачем холиварить я не пойму. Я привожу цитаты и доводы. У вас как то иначе что спорить и минусы притом паять

Comment: прошло, конечно, уже почти 3 года, но я действительно не могу понять в чем Aziz не прав? Если мы пойдем в англо-английский словарь и поищем там is, то он является глаголом